# Получить ветку из таблицы MySql

Tags: php, запрос, mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `cat_categories` (
   `cat_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
   `cat_parent` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
   `cat_name` char(56) NOT NULL default 'Category',
   PRIMARY KEY(`cat_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO `cat_categories` (`cat_id`, `cat_parent`, `cat_name`) VALUES 
(1, 0, 'Test Category 1'),
(2, 0, 'Test Category 2'),
(3, 1, 'Test Category 3'),
(4, 3, 'Test Category 4'),
```

Есть запрос, который создаёт таблицу с категориями, как **в PHP** проверить существование ветки, если знаем что

```
Test Category 1 -> Test Category 3 -> Test Category 4
```

Есть ли возможность не перебирать каждое значения, а сформировать `SQL` запрос, который будет формировать это значение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Деревья в SQL](http://gsbelarus.com/gs/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=314).

Может вам это поможет.
А вообще можно и через PHP сделать рекурсию.
Жаль в MySQL нету такой фичи как

```
WITH T 
(
    SELECT * FROM <Table>
    WHERE <field> = <someCondition>
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM <Table> JOIN T ON <SomeCondition>
)
```

В больших СУБД таких как `Oracle`, `MS SQL` данная фича решает все проблемы
В `mySQL` Вам, видимо, придется писать хранимку.